# How to 'scrollTo' a point on my Facebook page using Javascript and the "Facebook Page Plugin"?

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, scroll, autoscroll

So far I've loaded it into a div and tried scrolling the div, but this has not yet worked. I am using FF 40.0.2. I tried traversing through the DOMS within my div, however returns nothing when looking at the 'children'.innerHTML of my div.

Hopefully you will understand what I am trying to do with the code snippet below.

Any help would most appreciated! Thanks.

```html
<html> 
 <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.2" async></script>
 <body>
  <div align="center" style="background-color:#000000"><div id="fbDiv" class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-width="500" data-height="750" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true" data-adapt-container-width="false"></div></div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var y = 0;
  function test() {  
   var elmnt = document.getElementById("fbDiv");   
   alert(elmnt.children().first().innerHTML);
   //elmnt.scrollTop = 200;
  }
  
  /*function scroll() {
   var elmnt = document.getElementById("fbDiv");
   elmnt.scrollTop = elmnt.scrollTop + 1;
   if(elmnt.scrollTop == y){
    elmnt.scrollTop = 0;        
   } 
   y = elmnt.scrollTop;
  }*/
  
  setInterval(function(){ test(); }, 1500);
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The plugin creates an iframe that loads content from Facebook inside it, and as such you have no access to it via JavaScript from your domain, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Is there any alternative to using this plugin, that would not be incredibly difficult to implement? I would say that I am a novice->intermediate level coder, and I would be most comfortable staying within the realm of javascript/jQuery. Also the ability to 'auto-scroll' the page is a must. Thanks for your response CBroe.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve here? Grabbing a page’s post via API is certainly possible, but requires an access token. So if you want to do it purely client-side, you would need to have the viewing user login to your app first; with server-side code you could use a page or app access token as well.

Comment: I was trying to avoid access tokens. From what I understand you must have permissions to a page in order to get an access token. The facebook page I am trying to embed is not mine and I have no perms to it, however it is a public page. I would just like to embed this page, on a page in our domain and auto-scroll it, for kiosk viewing purposes without the user having to interactively scroll the page.

Comment: No, for a public page without any restrictions, you do not need the page’s authorization – a user access token or your app access token will do. Scrolling the page plugin is not possible, so you would need to create your on custom solution that gets the posts via API and displays them in your site.

Comment: (Unless you want to “hack” the scrolling in a way that you place the page plugin in a container element with `overflow:scroll` and a fixed height, and then scroll the content of that container. But the page plugin displays a maximum of five page posts, so there would probably not be that much to scroll to begin with.)

Comment: I was thinking that too. Do you know of any/can you provide any examples of this? Thanks for your help with this CBroe.